# How to solve unexpected Tor behaviour? User-agent and HTTPS protocol show my actual ip

Tags: python, request, ip, tor

I am trying to hide my ip adress by using Tor network.

I am using Tor expert bundle on windows.

I have run 2 tests to compare the different outputs.

I used two websites to detect the ip and the user-agent: `ipecho.net` and `httpbin.org`

First test results: call with HTTP protocol and default user-agent:

```
Ipecho found this ip: 199.249.230.64 (an expected Tor ip)
Httpbin found this ip: 199.249.230.64 (an expected Tor ip)
Ipecho found this user-agent: python-requests/2.22.0 (an expected default user-agent from requests)
Httpbin found this user-agent: python-requests/2.22.0 (an expected default user-agent from requests)
```

But on the second test results: call with HTTP protocol and a specific user agent

```
Ipecho found this ip: <MY ACTUAL IP> (my own unexpected ip)
Httpbin found this ip: 199.249.230.64 (an expected Tor ip)
Ipecho found this user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 (an expected user-agent that we specified)
Httpbin found this user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 (an expected user-agent that we specified)
```

I have two questions:

-Why `ipecho.net` and `httpbin.org` have different results on the second test?

-Why is my own ip showing up when I provide a user-agent in the header?

Here is the full code to reproduce these test results:

note: I have configured the torrc file to `ControlPort 9051` and also changed `HashedControlPassword`.

```
from torrequest import TorRequest # to make requests in Tor
import bs4 # to parse the responses
import json # to parse the responses

# we set up our requests for Tor with TorRequest
with TorRequest(proxy_port = 9050, ctrl_port = 9051, password = '<your password>') as tr:

    # we set up a specific user-agent that we will use on some tests
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'}

    # First test: we call with HTTP protocol and no specific user-agent
    response_ipecho_ip = tr.get('http://ipecho.net/plain')
    response_httpbin_ip = tr.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
    response_ipecho_agent = tr.get('http://ipecho.net/extra')
    response_httpbin_agent = tr.get('http://httpbin.org/user-agent')

    print('################ First test: we call with HTTP protocol and no specific user-agent ##############')
    print('Ipecho found this ip: {}'.format(response_ipecho_ip.text))
    response_httpbin_ip = json.loads(response_httpbin_ip.text)
    print('Httpbin found this ip: {}'.format(response_httpbin_ip['origin']))
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response_ipecho_agent.text,'html.parser')
    print('Ipecho found this user-agent: {}'.format(soup.find('tr').td.findNext('td').text))
    response_httpbin_agent = json.loads(response_httpbin_agent.text)
    print('Httpbin found this user-agent: {}\n'.format(response_httpbin_agent['user-agent']))

    # Second test: we call with HTTP protocol and a specific user agent
    response_ipecho_ip = tr.get('http://ipecho.net/plain', headers = headers)
    response_httpbin_ip = tr.get('http://httpbin.org/ip', headers = headers)
    response_ipecho_agent = tr.get('http://ipecho.net/extra', headers = headers)
    response_httpbin_agent = tr.get('http://httpbin.org/user-agent', headers = headers)

    print('################ Second test: we call HTTP protocol and a specific user agent ##############')
    print('Ipecho found this ip: {}'.format(response_ipecho_ip.text))
    response_httpbin_ip = json.loads(response_httpbin_ip.text)
    print('Httpbin found this ip: {}'.format(response_httpbin_ip['origin']))
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response_ipecho_agent.text,'html.parser')
    print('Ipecho found this user-agent: {}'.format(soup.find('tr').td.findNext('td').text))
    response_httpbin_agent = json.loads(response_httpbin_agent.text)
    print('Httpbin found this user-agent: {}\n'.format(response_httpbin_agent['user-agent']))
```

Also, bonus tests:
I run the same tests but this time with HTTPS. My own ip is always showing up, no matter if it's `ipecho.net` or `httpbin.org` and no matter if I use default user-agent or a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

Install "torrequest" from source. This bug [has been solved](https://github.com/erdiaker/torrequest/commit/8c1b5d0b90bbc5f302cc624a8ae61545542b99f4), but maybe not released.